# How to solve $y''+y=1+x^2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

> Solve $y''+y=1+x^2$.

First we can solve the homogeneous equation $y''+y=0$ using characteristic equation $m^2+1=0$ and we'll get $m=\pm i$.

Then the homogeneous solution is of form:
$$
y(x)=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x
$$
We can guess that the particular solution will be of form $y_p=a+bx+cx^2$. Then $y''_p=2c$.

Now we can plug in those guesses:
$$
2c+a+bx+cx^2=1+x^2
$$
Comparing the coefficients we get that $c=1, a=1,b=0$ then $y_p=1+x^2$.

**However,** the correct solution says $y_p=x^2-1$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that both $c$ and $a$ contribute to the constant term, so $2c+a=1$. In your answer $2c+a=3$.

Comment: @Ian absolutely missed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

the right hand side is an even polynomial function, so the particular  solution $y_p $  could be  polynomial.

$y_p $ and $y_p''$ could be both even.

Put $$y_p=Ax^2+B $$

then

$$y_p''+y_p=2A+Ax^2+B=1+x^2$$
and
$$A=1 \;\;,\;\;2A+B=1 \;\;, \;B=-1$$